# meta-analysis: computing effect sizes for correlation coefficients, regression coefficients, and odd ratios

Tags: correlation, regression-coefficients, sample-size, meta-analysis

I'm conducting a meta-analysis examining the associations between two variables. I came across studies using different analyses including correlations (r), multiple regression, hierarchical linear regression (B,β, R-squared), and logistic regression (odd ratios). I wonder what is the best way to convert these effect sizes and meta-analyze them? I found this website: https://www.escal.site. But I'm not sure if it's good. Any advice is appreciated.